# How do I get the viewController to fill my entire containerView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a `viewController` with a `containerView` filling the whole `viewController` (constrained to the `superView`). The `containerView` is `segued` to `embedd` a `navigationController` that `embedds` a `viewController` with a `tableView`.

It works displaying the `tableView` inside the `containerView`, but for some reason, the `tableView` doesn't fill the whole `containerView`. If I redirect the `containerView` `segue` to the `tableView` `viewController` directly instead of the `navigationController` if it works like a charm, so there seems to be some problem with the `navigationController` but I have no idea where to start to look. I have an image so that it becomes a bit more clear what I mean. Let me know if there is something more you need.

[image]

The pink `viewController` is just for test using another `containerView`. It works fine.

This is the result, end of the `tableView`. You can see that the `tableView` is cut off. Looking in the `debug hierarchy` The white part at the bottom is an underlying `view`, meaning that the `tableView` doesn't go all the way down to the `superView`.

[image]

***EDIT***
So, this is the constraints of the `containerView`. I have also tried setting them all to `superView` with the same result.

[image]

The `tableView` that I would like to add to the `container` is weird though as it doesn't have any `constraints`. But keep in mind that I get the desired results when I `embed` this `viewController` to the `containerView` rather than the `navigationController`. Can't see that the `tableView` has `constraints` set programatically either. I tried adding `constraints` to the `tableView` but they were grayed out. Not sure why or how to fix it. Perhaps this is where to start?

Comment: Check your Tableview constraints. or if you can show us the image of constraints that you have applied onto the TableView.

Comment: I added some more info. Hope that helps. Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your project...I can solve you problem in no time.

Comment: @MohitKumar Thank you so much for the offer. However, I just managed to solve it myself. Turns out the `storyBoard` was instantiated in the wrong way. Instead of going to the `viewController` with the `containerViews` it went straight to the `navigationController`. Missed that one heh. Again, thanks for being so helpful :D